# Issues with overriding the Mule Watermark (SF Polling) in flow via ObjectStore:store

Tags: mule

I have defined the object store as following:

```
<objectstore:config name="objectStore" objectStore-ref="_defaultUserObjectStore"/>
```

And am trying to modify the watermark variable defined by name "lastmodified" in object store via  a flow which call

```
<objectstore:store key="lastmodified" value-ref="#[payload.lastmodified]" overwrite="true" config-ref="objectStore" doc:name="Default User Object Store"/>
```

Note: payload.lastmodified has appropriate value of "2016-06-29T15:08:45.000Z" in it.

I am not seeing any error on console but when the next time the Poll executes it doesn't read the updated value of the watermark.

Any pointer would be surely helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the method used above, try using poll-watermarking. Can set you update expression in poll-watermarking and if needed, can use object store also.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining earlier. I have set watermark to be updated on each polling execution. However my use case was "if at all we want to modify the watermark on PROD how to do it". I have implemented the flow to do it and above questions was due to watermark not getting updated.

Comment: I fixed it by making changing the object store config to: <objectstore:config name="objectStore" 
   partition="mule.watermark"
   doc:name="ObjectStore: Connector"/>

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by making changing the object store config to: `<objectstore:config name="objectStore" partition="mule.watermark" doc:name="ObjectStore: Connector"/>`